Find the area of the largest circle centred at the origin which is inscribed between the graphs of the functions
Find the area of the largest circle centred at the origin which is inscribed between the graphs of the functions $$y = \frac{1}{1+x^2}, \hspace{2mm} \text{and} \hspace{2mm} y = \frac{-1}{1+x^2}$$

We are given a circle centred at origin so let's write it's equation
$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$
My idea is to find the minimum distance formula between these two curves namely, $y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\;$ and $\;y = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and set it equal to $0$ to get the value of $r$ or second thought that I'm having is, when the area is largest, the circle is tangent to the curve and that means $\sqrt{r^2-x^2} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ would have a double root at two points (one is just negative of the other) but I'm having trouble in the calculations of these two approaches.
Is there any other method I can use to find $r$ such that the area is maximum?

You could find the minimum distance from the origin to either of the two functions, and then set that distance $d$ as your radius.

OK that works, thanks

As suggested by @Asterix
Let $D(x)$ be the distance from the origin to the curve $y = \cfrac{1}{1+x^2}$

Notice that the radius of the circle is the minimum distance from the origin to the curve $y$

then $D(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \left(\cfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right)^2} \;$ and $\; D'(x) = \cfrac{x(1-2(1+x^2)^{-3})}{D(x)}$
$D'(x) = 0 \;$ gives $\; x = 0, \; \pm \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}$
where $x = 0$ gives local maxima and the other two gives local minima
So the radius, $r = D\left(\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}\right)$.
Therefore the circle's equation will be $$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$$
where $r = \sqrt{2^{1/3}-1+2^{-2/3}}$ and the largest area will be $$\text{Area} = 4\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \; dx = (3\sqrt[3]{2}-2)\arcsin(1)$$

The largest circle will touch the curves, so have the same gradient at the point of contact. That is, at the point of contact, $y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, $y^2+x^2=r^2$ and $\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}=-\frac{x}{y}$ (the right hand side from differentiating implicitly). Substituting from the first equation into the third gives $-2xy^2 =-\frac{x}{y}$, so $y^3=\frac{1}{2}$, since $x \neq 0$. The solution follows by substitution.

This is a matter of luck that you got the $y$ value easily. Better way is the one that @Asterix suggested

Actually, that isn't true. They are equally good - Asterix's method also depends on 'luck' that the equation $D'(x) = 0$ is soluble. In specific problems, it's often worth looking at both approaches to see which is technically easier. You can see the equivalence by writing the distance as a function of $y$: $D(y)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1+y^2}$, so $D'(y) = 0$ gives $\frac{-1}{y^2}+2y = 0$.
